# Adressing CoqIDE 8.11's "illegal begin of vernac" error with Functional Scheme

Tags: coq, coqide

I am somehow new to Coq, using CoqIDE 8.11, and can't see what I've done wrong here. I've checked the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/proof-schemes.html#generation-of-induction-principles-with-functional-scheme) but did not manage to find a solution to my problem.

With

```
Functional Scheme insert_ind := Induction for insert Sort Prop.
Check insert_ind.
```

I get a `Syntax error: illegal begin of vernac.` message.
Knowing that insert is earlier defined as follows:

```
Fixpoint insert l a :=
match l with
| nil => (a::nil)
| (b::l) =>
  match preOrdreImplem a b with
  | true => a::b::l
  | false => b:: (insert l a)
  end
end.
```

And that I've used it in the Lemma portion and encountered no issue.
Any help or hint much appreciated.

Comment: "First, it must be made available via `Require Import FunInd.`" Have you done that?

Comment: I hadnt. Now it works fine, thanks a lot. However I'm curious as to why I was able to go further in the proof using it without the import on a machine with an older version.

Comment: The meaning of `Require Import` has changed recently.  The previous meaning was impossible to document accurately, hence it was considered buggy.